# Does MongoDB store links or copies for related documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using mongoose and NodeJS, suppose I have an "Car" and a "Wheel" schema.  The car stores an array of wheels.

```
var Wheel = new Schema({
    color : { type: String },
    timestamp : { type: Date }
});

var Car = new Schema({
    wheels : [Wheel],
    timestamp : { type: Date }
});
```

Will a car document contain static copies of those wheels, or are the wheels stored as links (which will reflect the latest state of the wheel on lookup, even if the wheel has changed since the car was created).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broad choice of schema design here is [embedding versus linking](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design).  Both of these are implemented by usage conventions, and are not really a "feature" in the server implementation sense (i.e. the MongoDB 2.0 server does not implement any referential or relational lookup features).

To be clear on the terms:

- *Embedding* is the nesting of objects and arrays inside a BSON document.
- *Links* (aka *[Database References](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/)* or *DBRefs*) are references between documents.

If you *embed*, as in your original example, then you have created a subdocument (or as you described, a "static copy").  There is no relationship to information stored elsewhere.

If you *link* you are adding a reference which is the primary key for a document in another collection.  If you want to hydrate this reference into a document, an additional database query is required.  Depending on which client driver you use there may be a helper to automatically do this; you can also do the same lookup manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it in another way:

```
var Car = new Schema({
    wheels : [Schema.ObjectId],
    timestamp : { type: Date }
});
```

Then suppose I have 4 Wheels and one Car I do that:

```
car.wheels.push(wheel1._id);
car.wheels.push(wheel2._id);
car.wheels.push(wheel3._id);
car.wheels.push(wheel4._id);
```

I think Wheels need to be saved before, to have an _id property.

Then in MongoDB, the property Car.wheels, is an array of ObjectID (so a reference to the wheels) and I can do that in Javascript.

```
car.wheels[0].color
```

I suppose that it will work in the same way with your schema.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your case, it is static wheels in car.. To use reference, use dbref as:
`var Car = new Schema({

wheels : [ { type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Wheel' } ],

timestamp : { type: Date } });`